# Disable the administration email address verification (new in 5.3)

Tags: wp-admin, email-verification

In 5.3 a new function was introduced, on login you are reminded to confirm or update the administration email address of the site.
Is it possible to disable this completely?

I don't want to have this in my multisite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This new feature was added in 5.3 from core ticket [#46349](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/46349)

Currently (in 5.3) we have  [[src]](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.3/src/wp-login.php#L591) in `wp-login.php`:

```
 /**
  * Filters the interval for redirecting the user to the admin email confirmation screen.
  * If `0` (zero) is returned, the user will not be redirected.
  *
  * @since 5.3.0
  *
  * @param int Interval time (in seconds).
  */
  $admin_email_check_interval = (int) apply_filters( 'admin_email_check_interval', 6 * MONTH_IN_SECONDS );

  if ( $admin_email_check_interval > 0 ) {
     update_option( 'admin_email_lifespan', time() + $admin_email_check_interval );
  }
  wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to );
  exit;
```

and also the logic [[src](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.3/src/wp-login.php#L1235)]:

```
$admin_email_lifespan = (int) get_option( 'admin_email_lifespan' );

// If `0` (or anything "falsey" as it is cast to int) is returned, the user will not be redirected
// to the admin email confirmation screen.
/** This filter is documented in wp-login.php */
$admin_email_check_interval = (int) apply_filters( 'admin_email_check_interval', 6 * MONTH_IN_SECONDS );
if ( $admin_email_check_interval > 0 && time() > $admin_email_lifespan ) {
    $redirect_to = add_query_arg( 'action', 'confirm_admin_email', wp_login_url( $redirect_to ) );
}
```

So we can disable the screen by filtering the *admin email checking interval* to zero with a (must-use) plugin like:

```
<?php /** Plugin Name: WPSE-353167: Disable Admin Email Checking Screen **/
add_filter( 'admin_email_check_interval', '__return_zero' );
```

Here `__return_zero()` is a core [helper function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__return_zero/) that returns the zero integer. We could also return values that are not greater than zero when converted to an integer (e.g. `false`, `null`, `'0'`, ... ).

There's also an open ticket [#48153](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/48153) to make this more flexible regarding the capability filtering.

Here are the published the [dev notes](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/10/17/wordpress-5-3-admin-email-verification-screen/).